# What is the best way to sleep threads without using a busy wait implementation?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

so I'm trying to reduce the CPU utilization in my mock operating system. I have a function to suspend execution of a calling thread until time has advanced by at least x timer ticks. Unless the system is idle, the thread doesn't have to wake up after exactly x ticks have passed, it is placed back in the ready threads queue after it's waited for the right amount of ticks. Ideally there's some semaphore implementation for this, but I don't know how. That said, if you have a better solution to semaphores, it would be interesting to hear that also.

For some reference here's the initial code with descriptions:

```
void timer_sleep (int64_t ticks){

  int64_t start = timer_ticks ();

  ASSERT (intr_get_level () == INTR_ON);
  while (timer_elapsed (start) < ticks)
    thread_yield ();
}
```

`timer_ticks` - gives us how many ticks have passed since the OS started.

`timer_elapsed` - tells us the amount of `timer_ticks()` passed since another number of ticks.

`intr_get_level` - is used to get the value of whether or not interrupts are enabled or disabled.

`thread_yield` - This Yields the CPU. The current thread is not put to sleep and may be scheduled again immediately at the schedulers whim.

Comment: [WFI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360e/CHDEEIJB.html) on ARMs, [MWAIT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mwait) on Intel's. What does "mock operating system" means?

Comment: as in an OS that I'm working on/developing, just to learn more.

Comment: One efficient way to sleep, without using extra resources is to wait for (timer) interrupt